# XP Mode as a server, Win 7 as a client

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-xp-mode

I have two virtual machines (XP Mode). They are connected to each other by a network setting - Internal Network. It is the only working setting. This is the only way I got two virtual XP to ping each other.

Now I want to connect each of them from the application that runs on Windows 7 which is hosting both virtual machines, but I can't do that.

The firewall on both XP-Mode machines is disabled. Any other networking setting added as additional adapter on Xp-Mode machine does not allow me to connect from Windows 7.

So my question is this - **how to enable connection from Windows 7 application to XP mode application (client - server)**?

[image: The layout]

Point 2 (pass message) work perfectly because of the "internal network" setting. The problem is point 1 and 3.

Comment: You need to enable bridged networking, to allow the machines to see each other on the same network.

Comment: How do I do that? Do I have to add some virtual network card in Windows 7? Both XP machines already see each other. They also see Windows 7 if I add a network setting for physical network card. The problem is that Windows 7 has to somehow connect to virtual machine (XP-mode).

Comment: I don't have a Windows 7 machine near me right now, but I believe this is in the network card setting on the VM properties (I think it's called "Settings").

Comment: Believe me, I have set every permutation of that. Still can't ping virtual machine from Windows 7.